# jQuery transition between themes (when switching theme)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, themes, transition

I have this:

```
<html lang="en" theme="dark">
```

and this:

```
html {
  &[theme='light'] {
    --bg: #ffffff;
    --title: #6822c4;
    --sub-title: #000000;
    --text: #ffffff;
  }
  &[theme='dark'] {
    --bg: #17171F;
    --title: #4578a5;
    --sub-title: #acacac;
    --text: #ffdddd;
  }
}
```

and this:

```
$('#myCheckBox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) document.documentElement.setAttribute('theme', 'dark')
        else document.documentElement.setAttribute('theme', 'light')
});
```

and that's working perfectly BUT there is no transition, so I was wondering if I can deal something with jQuery, like a fadeOut or something?

Comment: Theme the `body` instead.

Comment: Done, but that's not adding a transition at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to the elements you want to change:

```js
$('#myCheckBox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) document.documentElement.setAttribute('theme', 'dark')
  else document.documentElement.setAttribute('theme', 'light')
});
```

```css
html[theme='light'] {
  --bg: #ffffff;
  --title: #6822c4;
  --sub-title: #000000;
  --text: #000000;
}

html[theme='dark'] {
  --bg: #17171F;
  --title: #4578a5;
  --sub-title: #eeeeee;
  --text: #ffffff;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg);
  transition: background-color 600ms linear;
}

label {
  color: var(--text);
  cursor: pointer;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--title);
}

h2 {
  color: var(--sub-title);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" theme="dark">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Test">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <label>Dark theme
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" name="checkbox_theme" checked>
</label>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Sub-Title</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @db1975 already answered your question. Will leave my example for further illustration.

Comment: Thanks for answering me! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

you must add transition in your css

```js
$('#myCheckBox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('html').attr('theme', 'dark')
        else $('html').attr('theme', 'light')
});
```

```css
  html body {
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  html[theme='light'] body {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  html[theme='dark'] body {
    background: #17171F;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en" theme="dark">
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" value="1" checked>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me! Have a great day!